# Holomorphic structure on complex line bundle determined by connection

Tags: complex-geometry

Consider we have a unitary connection on a given complex line bundle, if we have the (0,2) part of the curvature associated to the connection is 0, how can we see that this connection determine a holomorphic structure on the line bundle?

Comment: Your connection $\nabla$ on the bundle $L$ spits as $\partial_L + \bar \partial_L$, where $\bar \partial_L$ is a $\bar \partial$-operator. The $(0,2)$-part of the curvature $\nabla \wedge \nabla$ is exactly $\bar \partial_L \wedge \bar \partial_L$. Now, depending on your point of view, a holomorphic structure on $L$ *is* a $\bar \partial$-operator such that $\bar \partial_L \wedge \bar \partial_L = 0$. See perhaps the book of Kobayashi: Differential geometry of complex vector bundles

Comment: @NicolasTholozan I get the point. Thanks!